SQL modeler not loading properly and stuck at starting
My Oracle Sql Modeler is not loading.
Any help,
I have downloaded from the Oracle website.
Regards,
Fabrice
enter image description here
I have try the version on Oracle for Windows 11 but Oracle Sql Modeler is not opening.Its stuck at the loading screen as in the screenshot.
Any help,
thanks,
Fabrice
